# Struggling to map through nested object.. React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

Trying to map through instagrams api return but struggling to get the syntax right and its driving me crazy.

```
      <img src={feeds.data[0].media_url} />
      {feeds.map((feed) => (
        <Feed key={feed.id} feed={feed} />
      ))}
```

In the first line of code, I was able to get one picture to show up then after rerendering, it doesn't work.
the second line is how im trying to pass each item in the array to another component called Feed which will render it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It depends on the initial state of `feeds`. It will throw an error if it is not an array mapping over. Also, in your case, the `feeds` is an object with a property called `data`, which you ignored, and you have to iterate over the `data` instead of `feeds`.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, I figured it out by doing the below.
I haven't figured out why, but the `?` makes the code work for me. I will update you when I figure it out.

```
{
  feeds.data?.map((data, _index) => (
     <div key={_index}>
         <Feed key={data.id} feed={data} />
     </div>
  ))
}
```

Comment: It is not working without [`?` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) because there is no initial state for `feeds.data`, which has to be an empty array (`[]`).  The `?` operator will ignore the rest of the chaining if the current element is `undefined` or `null` so the `map` won't run in the first place, and there won't be any errors.

Comment: @SMAKSS That makes so much sense. So once the data is actually updated, it will then run the rest of the code instead of throwing an error? Thank you for explaining!